# How do i refresh my listbox with the new data?

Tags: c#, sql, database, wpf, listbox

I have a listbox that shows all rows from a database.
When i edit a row from the listbox/database the edit wont show up in the list box until i restart the program. How do i fix so that the listbox updates with the edit after i've clicked the "Save Changes" button?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string connectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Library;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            var query = "SELECT * FROM Author";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Author a = new Author();
                        a.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                        a.Name = reader.GetString(1);
                        a.Nationality = reader.GetString(2);

                        AuthorListBox.Items.Add(a.Name);

                        Book b = new Book();
                        b.BookId = reader.GetInt32(0);
                        //b.AuthorID = reader.GetInt32(1);
                        b.Title = reader.GetString(2);

                        BookListBox.Items.Add(b.BookId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void SaveChangesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Library;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                string query = "UPDATE Author SET AuthorId = '" + this.IdTextBox.Text + "' ," +
                    " Name = '" + this.AuthorNameTextBox.Text + "', Nationality = '" + this.NationalityTextBox.Text +
                    "' WHERE AuthorId = '" + this.IdTextBox.Text + "' ";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Updated the author");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like you are not reading the changes back that you made to your database. You only add Author objects to your BookListBox.Items collection in your Constructor.

Easyiest way would probably be to read everything from your database again after adding an element and update your BookListBox.Items collection.By the way dont forget to call refresh().

Comment: Thanks i'll look into that.
Should i call refresh() after `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` ?

Comment: call it after adding all new elements to your VookListBox.Items collection.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to put the the code that retrieves database values into a method e.g.

public void getData(){

}

Then when you are updating the author call this method immediately after the MessageBox.Show("Updated the author");

Try that, if it can't work can give you another angle.

also put your connection strings in a function/method to avoid repeating yourself when opening database connectivity

Answer (score 0):

Extract the contents of the `MainWindow()` into a different function. And call the new function at the end of `SaveChangesButton_Click`. Also don't forget to clear the listbox before refreshing the contents.

Something like this

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadFromDatabase();
    }
    public LoadFromDatabase()
    {

        BookListBox.Items.Clear(); //Without this you'll get an ever expanding list
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Library;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            var query = "SELECT * FROM Author";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Author a = new Author();
                        a.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                        a.Name = reader.GetString(1);
                        a.Nationality = reader.GetString(2);

                        AuthorListBox.Items.Add(a.Name);

                        Book b = new Book();
                        b.BookId = reader.GetInt32(0);
                        //b.AuthorID = reader.GetInt32(1);
                        b.Title = reader.GetString(2);

                        BookListBox.Items.Add(b.BookId);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }

    private void SaveChangesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Library;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                string query = "UPDATE Author SET AuthorId = '" + this.IdTextBox.Text + "' ," +
                " Name = '" + this.AuthorNameTextBox.Text + "', Nationality = '" + this.NationalityTextBox.Text +
                "' WHERE AuthorId = '" + this.IdTextBox.Text + "' ";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Updated the author");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

        }
        LoadFromDatabase();
    }
}
```